# What are good resources on idempotent semirings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, idempotents, semiring

I have recently become interested in idempotent semirings, but I haven't been able to find any good expository text on them. What are good resources for a graduate student to learn about idempotent semirings from an algebraic (rather than an applied) perspective? Textbooks or quality pdfs would suffice. Assume a solid background in graduate algebra in general but little previous exposure to idempotent semirings in particular.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back when I was thinking about such things, I found these two resources valuable. They do study idempotent semirings and structures at length.

> Golan, Jonathan S. Semirings and their Applications. Springer Science & Business Media, 2013.
>
> Gondran, Michel, and Michel Minoux. Graphs, dioids and semirings: new models and algorithms. Vol. 41. Springer Science & Business Media, 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the books mentioned above, there is a recent article [Finite simple additively idempotent semirings](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869313002299) with more references.